# How to insert data into the same row and column - mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I'm working on a project using PHP and MySQL. I want to know if I'm able to input multiple amounts of data into the same row and column.

For example:

```
id       leader_id      student_id
____________________________________
1     |       3      |  1, 2, 3
      |              |
```

So basically I want the user to input the team `leader_id`, and then the 3 other team member's ID. Also, I would like to know how I would be able to select each `student_id` individually.

Comment: **Do not store multiple values as one single delimited value.** See Normalization

Comment: Agreeing with @GurV , you should avoid CSV in your table.  You might want to start with a good MySQL tutorial rather than posting here.

Comment: It's cerrtainly not a good practice. However, in case you're compelled to do it this way, please share what you've tried so far. Please show your input/POST data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could accomplish that but don't.  Instead create a record for each leader_id to student_id combination so it will look like the following:

```
id       leader_id      student_id
____________________________________
1     |       3      |  1
2     |       3      |  2
3     |       3      |  3
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do like this:

```
id       leader_id      student_id
____________________________________
1     |       3      |  1, 2, 3
      |              |
```

Then you could query the "student_id" as a string and using the "explode" function to operate each member of "student_id".

Also you can refer to this web site: http://www.w3school.com.cn/php/func_string_explode.asp